# Issues with syntax highlighting (r tag)

Tags: bug, syntax-highlighting

I've noticed that there seem to be issues with the syntax highlighting.

Take [this recent post](https://stats.stackexchange.com/q/548609/11849) as an example:

[image: screenshot of example]

Clearly, the question is tagged [r](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/r). Thus, R syntax highlighting should be applied. However, it isn't. You can easily see that because comments (starting with `#`) should be grey. I suspect a default (C?) highlighting is applied. The strange thing is that in some posts correct syntax highlighting is used ([example](https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/548357/11849)) and in some not.

Here is a screenshot from Stack Overflow showing the correct syntax highlighting:

[image: screenshot from post rendered at Stack Overflow]

Comment: Even adding `<!-- lang-all: lang-r -->` doesn't seem to work :-(.

Comment: It's a bug, probably not only related to CrossValidated.com, but likely also other sites, so I'm moving it to the Meta site.

Comment: @Tim you can fix it yourself, at the bottom of [this page](https://stats.stackexchange.com/tags/r/info). On SO, the setting is correct: https://stackoverflow.com/tags/r/info

Comment: @Glorfindel thanks, I wasn't aware of this setting.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I learned something new today. Apparently the tag wiki pages have default syntax highlighting setting on the bottom and we used the default one for the  `[r]` tag (for Python it is correct).

Now it's fixed.

[image]

Alternatively, remember that you can always use

```
<!-- lang-all: lang-r -->
```

somewhere in the body of the post to set highlighting for all snippets, or start the snippet with

````
```lang-r
````

Comment: I wonder how it got changed. The setting for the `[r]` tag used to be correct.  Also, I tried `<!-- lang-all: lang-r -->` on the linked page & it didn't turn on the correct syntax highlighting, but I spent very little time on it.

Comment: @gung-ReinstateMonica unfortunately I have no idea as well.